# A synthetic geometrical proof required on a result regarding Isosceles triangles.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I need a synthetic proof on this problem without the use of trigonometry.

[image]
**Question:**
Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $AB=AC$. If $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$, $E$ the foot of perpendicular drawn from $D$ to $AC$ and $F$ the midpoint of $DE$, prove that $AF\perp BE$.

The proof is very easy using coordinate geometry.

**I'm stuck at:** Since point $F$ is midpoint of $DE$, it is fixed and is not a trivial information. But I can't see a way to use this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be a midpoint for $CE$. Then $DG$ is a middle line in triangle $BCE$ so $DG||BE$. Also we see that $FG||DC$ so $FG\bot AD$. So $F$ is an orthocenter in triangle $ADG$. So ...

Comment: Nice solution! +1

Comment: Really nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be a midpoint of $BD$.

Thus, since $$\Delta ABD\sim\Delta DCE,$$ we obtain:
$$\frac{AB}{DC}=\frac{BD}{CE}$$ or
$$\frac{2AB}{BC}=\frac{2BK}{CE}$$ or
$$\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{BK}{CE}$$ and since $\measuredangle ABK=\measuredangle BCE,$ we obtain
$$\Delta ABK\sim\Delta BCE,$$
which gives
$$\measuredangle BKA=\measuredangle BEC.$$
Now, let $BE\cap AK=\{L\}.$

Thus, $$\measuredangle BLA=\measuredangle LAE+\measuredangle BEA=\measuredangle KAD+180^{\circ}-\measuredangle BEC=$$
$$=\measuredangle KAD+180^{\circ}-\measuredangle BKA=180^{\circ}-90^{\circ}=90^{\circ}.$$